# How to copy the contents of a Multiline textbox to the clipboard in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, copy-paste

I have some text coming from database in a Multiline textbox, how can I copy that to the clipboard so that the user can paste it into another window or file (e.g. from my application to another textbox)? OR to notepad/word file if possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Clipboard.Clear();    //Clear if any old value is there in Clipboard        
Clipboard.SetText("abc"); //Copy text to Clipboard
string strClip = Clipboard.GetText(); //Get text from Clipboard
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in copying text from a single or multiline `TextBox` to and from the clipboard using `Clipboard.SetText()` (and of course `Clipboard.GetText()`). A `TextBox` will still contain a single `String`, whether it contains line breaks or not. That's only eye candy.

From a limitations perspective, your `ClipBoard.SetText()` method will always only accept one single string as well, its size only limited by and to the amount of free memory at that given time.

No special code is needed to paste this text manually into applications like Notepad or Word.

`Clipboard.SetText(yourTextBox.Text);` is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

For saving lines in text you should replace "\n" to NewLine character, as in example:

```
 string textforClipboard = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
 Clipboard.Clear();
 Clipboard.SetText(textforClipboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(..)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext.aspx